# Add legend to images from json file

Tags: javascript, frameworks, legend

i'm searching for a Javascript framework that can help me to add legends to images i have in my database. 
What i have : 
-> a JSON file that contains all the legends with its coordinates on the image.

**Ex. i have this image :** **225_4.png**

[image: 225_4.png] 
the JSON content that suits the image : `{image": "225_4.png", "height": 37.16999999999996, "width": 65.46599999999998, "y": 67.57999999999993, "x": -62.54000000000005, "legend": "Vertebral  _RL_ foramen _RL_ "}`

it's a web app so i'm developping in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a `canvas`.

Here is an example:

```js
var context = canvasElm.getContext("2d");

context.font = "20px serif";
context.fillStyle = "lightgreen";
  
$("#canvasElm").mousemove(function(e){

  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElm.width, canvasElm.height);// clear the canvas

  // check if the mouse pointer is over the sun or one of the planets.
  if(e.clientX >= 0 && e.clientX < 82 && e.clientY >= 0 && e.clientY < 126){
    context.fillText("The Sun", e.clientX, e.clientY);
  }else if(e.clientX >= 95 && e.clientX < 105 && e.clientY >= 60 && e.clientY < 70){
    context.fillText("Mercury", e.clientX, e.clientY);
  }else if(e.clientX >= 124 && e.clientX < 134 && e.clientY >= 58 && e.clientY < 68){
    context.fillText("Venus", e.clientX, e.clientY);
  }
});
```

```css
img, canvas{
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif"/>
  <canvas id="canvasElm"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

If you run this snipped and you put your pointer over the sun or one of the planets you will see some text will appear at the pointer's position.

All you'll have to do to replace the `img` element's source and inside the `mousemove` callback function check if the pointer's position is over an area defined inside your legend object.